# Multi-line string to array

Tags: java, arrays, guava

I have a multi-line string:

```
40 40 40 
100 100 100
200 200 200
100 50 200 100
150 150 150
50 60 70 80 90
```

and I need it as 2D array. I was trying to do it by split, guava Splitter and couple of more techniques but it still doesn't want to work.

```
public void readTextFile() throws IOException {
        content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/home/cosaquee/dane.txt")));

        Splitter niceCommaSplitter = Splitter.on('\n').omitEmptyStrings().trimResults();

        Iterable<String> tokens2 = niceCommaSplitter.split(content);

        for(String token: tokens2){
            boolean atleastOneAlpha = token.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");
            if (!atleastOneAlpha) {
                arrayList.add(token);
                System.out.println(token);
            }
        }
    }
```

That is my code for now. I have arraylist with every line but I don't know how to make it to 2D array. I tried good old `for`s but don't know how to iterate over every string and split them and save to array.

Comment: why not two good old for's? we may be able to help you further if you show us the code of what you tried with split, etc.

Comment: edited to show what i have now, every line of code that i wrote to save it to array wasn`t working so i don`t have anything to show sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use a Splitter? String comes with a split() method. Also, just use a double for loop to fill up your 2d array.

```
public String[][] readTextFile() throws IOException {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("yourpath.txt")));

    // get the lines
    String[] lines = content.split("\\r?\\n"); // split on new lines

    // get the max amt of nums in the file in a single line
    int maxInLine = 0;
    for (String x : lines) {
        String[] temp = x.split("\\s+"); // split on whitespace
        if (temp.length > maxInLine) {
            maxInLine = temp.length;
        }
    }

    String[][] finalArray = new String[lines.length][maxInLine]; // declare and instantiate the array of arrays

    // standard double for loop to fill up your 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String[] temp = lines[i].split("\\s+"); // split on whitespace
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            finalArray[i][j] = temp[j];
        }
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: String.split is rather crappy, that's one reason why `Splitter` exists. It's also more powerful. Without `omitEmptyStrings` / `trimResults`, you'll get crap from trailing blanks and trailing empty lines.

Comment: @maaartinus Fair enough, although I've never run into a problem with .split(), i'll keep in mind the Splitter as an alternative in case something does go wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using Guava, you can produce a list of lists in a one-liner -- applying a [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) for each row that takes as input a `String` containing whitespace-separated columns and outputting the columns of the row as `List<String>`. If you prefer a 2d array of strings, then you need some more code:

```
public void readTextFile() throws IOException {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths
            .get("/home/cosaquee/dane.txt")));

    // convert the string into a list of lists, corresponding to a 2d string array
    List<List<String>> twoDimensionalList = Lists
            .transform(Splitter.on(System.lineSeparator()).splitToList(content),
                    new Function<String, List<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public List<String> apply(String row) {
                            return Splitter.on(" ").splitToList(row);
                        }
                    });

    // convert the list of lists into a 2d array
    String[][] twoDimensionalArray = new String[twoDimensionalList.size()][];

    for (int i = 0; i < twoDimensionalArray.length; i++) {
        twoDimensionalArray[i] = twoDimensionalList.get(i).toArray(
                new String[twoDimensionalList.get(i).size()]);
    }

    // assert that we got it right
    for (String[] row : twoDimensionalArray) {
        for (String col : row) {
            System.out.print(col + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```